# MongoDB - Upsert with increment

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to run the following query:

```
data = {
    'user_id':1,
    'text':'Lorem ipsum',
    '$inc':{'count':1}, 
    '$set':{'updated':datetime.now()},
}
self.db.collection('collection').update({'user_id':1}, data, upsert=True)
```

but the two '$' queries cause it to fail. Is it possible to do this within one statement?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, when you ask a question like this it's very helpful to add information on why it's failing (e.g. copy the error).

Your query fails because you're mixing $ operators with document overrides. You should use the $set operator for the `user_id` and text fields as well (although the `user_id` part in your update is irrelevant at this example).

So convert this to pymongo query:

```
db.test.update({user_id:1}, 
    {$set:{text:"Lorem ipsum", updated:new Date()}, $inc:{count:1}}, 
    true, 
    false)
```

I've removed the `user_id` in the update because that isn't necessary. If the document exists this value will already be 1. If it doesn't exist the upsert will copy the query part of your update into the new document.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do the following:
If the doc doesn't exist, insert a new doc.
If it exists, then only increment one field.
Then you can use a combo of $setOnInsert and $inc. If the song exists then $setOnInsert won't do anything and $inc will increase the value of "listened". If the song doesn't exist, then it will create a new doc with the fields "songId" and "songName". Then $inc will create the field and set the value to be 1.

```
let songsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      songId: String,
      songName: String,
      listened: Number
    })
    
let Song = mongoose.model('Song', songsSchema);
let saveSong = (song) => {
  return Song.updateOne(
    {songId: song.songId},
    {
      $inc: {listened: 1},
      $setOnInsert: {
        songId: song.songId,
        songName: song.songName,
      }
    },
    {upsert: true}
  )
  .then((savedSong) => {
    return savedSong;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR SAVING SONG IN DB', err);
  })
```